# Launcher icon (to start a script) keeps blinking and is unresponsive for seven seconds, how can I solve it?

Tags: unity, scripts, 15.10, launcher

I have a script, which I start from the Unity Launcher. When I click on the icon, my script starts successfully.

While the script only takes a split second to run, the launcher icon blinks for about 7-8 sec., during which the launcher is occupied and doesn't respond to additional clicks.

Can I customize my bash script in such a way that the blinking icon doesn't block the script for seven seconds?

I use Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Hi klpu, posted my answer. please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Not a dupe

***Very much*** related [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744173/custom-right-click-action-in-unity-launcher-keeps-cursor-busy-for-20-seconds/744191#744191), but slightly different, since the blinking, non-responsive icon is a different problem, *not* solved by adding:

```
StartupNotify=false
```

to the launcher; the icon will still keep blinking for appr. seven seconds. Although the issues in both questions have the same background, both the symptoms and the possible solution are slightly different.

#### The cause

After starting GUI applications from the Unity Launcher (by clicking on the icon), the launcher waits for a window to appear. While waiting, the cursor blinks. It takes the launcher a while before it comes to the conclusion that its "date" (the window) won't show up. *While* waiting however, the launcher does not accept new clicks to execute the script (again).

The solution in the above linked question, adding

```
StartupNotify=false
```

*does* solve the spinning wheel of the mouse cursor, but does *not* make the icon responsive again.

#### Then what does work?

The other solution in the linked answer however (opening a fake, invisible window when starting a non- GUI script from the Unity launcher) will also solve the issue of the blinking icon.

*From the linked answer:*

1. Create, if it does not exist yet, the directory `~/bin`
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `fake_window` (no extension) in `~/bin` ***and make it executable***

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   from gi.repository import Gtk
   from threading import Thread
   import time
   import subprocess

   """
   This is a self-destroying window, to "feed" Unity a fake-window, preventing
   the launcher to show a spinning wheel, waiting for a window to appear.
   Include the command to run this script at the end of the (your) script.
   """

   class FakeWin(Gtk.Window):

       def __init__(self):
           Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="1526closeme")
           Thread(target = self.close).start()

       def close(self):
           t = 0
           while t < 150:
               time.sleep(0.2)
               try:
                   pid = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "-f", "fake_window"])\
                         .decode("utf-8").strip()
                   subprocess.Popen(["kill", pid])
                   break
               except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                   pass
               t += 1

   def fakewindow():
       window = FakeWin()
       # make our window transparent
       window.set_opacity(0)
       window.set_default_size(0,0)
       window.show_all()
       Gtk.main()

   fakewindow()
   ```
3. Add to the very end of your script the command:

   ```
   fake_window
   ```
4. ***Log out and back in*** (or run `source ~/.profile`)

Now the icon will not blink for seven seconds if you run your script from the Unity Launcher.