# Can I have a window showing small live preview of another workspace?

Tags: unity, workspaces

Is it possible to mirror a live section of one workspace so that it is visible in the current workspace as a window that can be moved around?

The other day I had a Windows 10 VM running on my Ubuntu 16.04 host that took a really long time to complete updating.  I kept checking on its progress via Expo (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) on Ubuntu.  That got me thinking that this problem has most likely been solved already since tools such as simplescreenrecorder can be configured to record just a portion of the screen.  However, I don't know the proper terminology to use for my Google search.

I'd like to see the 300x150 screenshot below in the form of a floating window (with live updates) in the top right corner of whichever workspace happens to be current.

[image]

Comment: @serg here a new project for you

Comment: @Rinzwind you must hate Serg... We (both) have been looking at something like this before, didn't succeed.

Comment: I even put a bounty on it this time :=) get to it @JacobVlijm

Comment: Would be a cool feature :) It won't help in the VM case, but there is a solution for terminal applications: using Konsole. It has two useful options: "notify on activity" and "notify on silence". The first one will send you a notification when a new line is shown in the terminal (useful when using `tail -F file | grep pattern` on logs to be warned of some events), the second one will send you notification when there's been some time since last written line (useful to know when a build has ended).

Comment: @Rinzwind holy crap, it is going to work...

Comment: This may be a silly question, but if you're using VirtualBox, have you thought of using the remote display option?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### EDIT

*(New answer)*

**DONE.**
The answer below is now available in a polished form, as an indicator, as a ppa for Trusty, Xenial, Yakkety and Zesty :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:vlijm/windowspy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install windowspy
```

Th indicator (including preview window) is now nicely low on juice. Options include a settings window, setting window border size/color, window size.

[image]

In the meantime, I found it useful to keep an eye on the AU window; see if there are any messages :)

---

**OLD ANSWER**

*(<strike>first</strike> second rough concept)*

#### Have a minimized representation of a window on another workspace

To my own (big) surprise, it can be *effectively* done, be it with 
trickery and deceit; have an updated representation of a window on another workspace. *Not* fit to watch a movie, definitely good enough to keep an eye on a window elsewhere (example: my tv-card window):

#### How it works in practice

1. With the window in front, press a shortcut key:

   [image]

   (the window will minimize)
2. Move to another workspace, press the shortcut key again, a small representation of the window will appear, updated every 4 seconds:

   [image]

   The window always shows on top of other windows. As it is, the window is 300px (width), but can be set to any size.
3. To end it, press (again) the shortcut key. The small window will close, you will move to the viewport of the original window, which will appear again, unminimized.

#### The scripts

1. The control script

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import os
   import sys
   import time

   # paths
   imagepath = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], ".showcase")
   wfile = os.path.join(imagepath, "currentwindow")
   vpfile = os.path.join(imagepath, "last_vp")
   # setup path
   if not os.path.exists(imagepath):
       os.mkdir(imagepath)

   def get(command):
       try:
           return subprocess.check_output(command).decode("utf-8").strip()
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
           pass

   def get_vp():
       open(vpfile, "wt").write(get(["wmctrl", "-d"]).split()[5])

   def run(command):
       subprocess.Popen(command)

   def convert_tohex(widxd):
       return widxd[:2]+((10-len(widxd))*"0")+widxd[2:]

   def check_windowtype(wid):
       check = get(["xprop", "-id", wid])
       return not any([s in check for s in [
           "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK",
           "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP"]])

   def edit_winprops(wid, convert=True):
       run(["xdotool", "windowminimize", wid])
       if convert:
           widxd = convert_tohex(hex(int(wid)))
       else:
           widxd = wid
       run(["wmctrl", "-i", "-r", widxd, "-b", "add,sticky"])
       get_vp()
       open(os.path.join(imagepath, "currentwindow"), "wt").write(widxd)

   def initiate_min():
       # if not, minmize window, write the file
       wid = get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])
       if check_windowtype(wid):
           edit_winprops(wid)
       else:
           pidinfo = [l.split() for l in wlist.splitlines()]
           match = [l for l in pidinfo if all([
               get(["ps", "-p", l[2], "-o", "comm="]) == "VirtualBox",
               not "Manager" in l])]
           if match:
               edit_winprops(match[0][0], convert=False)

   # windowlist
   wlist = get(["wmctrl", "-lp"])

   if "Window preview" in wlist:
       # kill the miniwindow
       pid = get(["pgrep", "-f", "showmin"])
       run(["kill", pid])
       window = open(wfile).read().strip()
       viewport = open(vpfile).read().strip()
       run(["wmctrl", "-o", viewport])
       time.sleep(0.3)
       run(["wmctrl", "-i", "-r", window, "-b", "remove,sticky"])
       run(["wmctrl", "-ia", window])
       os.remove(wfile)

   else:
       # check if windowfile exists
       wfileexists = os.path.exists(wfile)
       if wfileexists:
           # if file exists, try to run miniwindow
           window = open(wfile).read().strip()
           if window in wlist:
               # if the window exists, run!
               run(["showmin", window])
           else:
               # if not, minmize window, write the file
               initiate_min()
       else:
           # if not, minmize window, write the file
           initiate_min()
   ```
2. The window representatiom

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import gi
   gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
   from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
   from PIL import Image
   import os
   import subprocess
   import time
   from threading import Thread
   import sys

   wid = sys.argv[1]
   xsize = 300

   imagepath = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], ".showcase")
   if not os.path.exists(imagepath):
       os.mkdir(imagepath)
   img_in = os.path.join(imagepath, "image.png")
   resized = os.path.join(imagepath, "resized.png")

   def get_img():
       subprocess.Popen([
           "import", "-window", wid, "-resize", str(xsize),  resized
           ])

   get_img()

   class Splash(Gtk.Window):

       def __init__(self):
           Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Window preview")
           maingrid = Gtk.Grid()
           self.add(maingrid)
           self.image = Gtk.Image()
           # set the path to the image below
           self.resized = resized
           self.image.set_from_file(self.resized)
           maingrid.attach(self.image, 0, 0, 1, 1)
           maingrid.set_border_width(3)
           self.update = Thread(target=self.update_preview)
           self.update.setDaemon(True)
           self.update.start()

       def update_preview(self):
           while True:
               get_img()
               time.sleep(3)
               GObject.idle_add(
                   self.image.set_from_file, self.resized,
                   priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                   )

   def miniwindow():
       window = Splash()
       window.set_decorated(False)
       window.set_resizable(False)
       window.set_keep_above(True)
       window.set_wmclass("ShowCase", "showcase")
       window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
       GObject.threads_init()
       window.show_all()
       window.move(70, 50)
       Gtk.main()

   miniwindow()
   ```

#### How to use

1. Install `python3-pil`, `xdotool` and `wmctrl`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl python3-pil
   ```
2. Create, if it doesn't exist yet, the directory `~/bin`.
3. Copy script 1, he control script, as (exactly) `showcase_control` (no extension) in `~/bin`, and ***make it executable***.
4. Copy script 2, the mini- window script, as (exactly) `showmin` (no extension) in `~/bin`, and ***make it executable***.
5. Log out and back in, and add the following command to a shortcut of your choice:

   ```
   showcase_control
   ```

   Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   showcase_control
   ```

   and it should work!

   - Press the key once to grab the current window
   - move to the other workspace where you'd like the mini-window
   - Press again to show the miniwindow
   - Press again to move back to the original workspace, (automatically)  un-minimize the original window and close the mini -one.

#### Downsides?

- The setup, as it is currently,  adds *some* work for your processor. On my (very) old system however, it adds (on average) appr. 4-5% I reckon, which I did not notice in *any* way.

  **Update:** It turns out `import` can resize the image in one step, together with *fetching* the window image. This means a substantial reduction in processor load. At the same time the refresh time is shorter (3 seconds now), still at lower "costs".

#### Explanation

- My starting point was the way OP mentioned he wanted to use the option to keep an eye on a window on another workspace, waiting for either something to finish.
- While *literally* having an exact (mini) copy of a window on another workspace seems impossible, we *can* make an image of an existing window with the `import` -command, once we have the window id. While this both works on minimized windows or windows without focus, there is however one issue: the window needs to be *on the current workspace*.
- The trick is then to temporarily (while the mini- window is used) make the window "sticky" (be virtually available on all workspaces) with `wmctrl`, but minimized at the same time.
- Since all is done automatically, the difference *effectively* is none, since also returning to the initial viewport, "un-" sticky the original window and un- minimizing it, is done automatically.

#### In short:

1. Pressing the shortcut once: targeted window is made sticky, but minimized
2. Pressing it again (presumably on another workspace): a small mini- version of the window appears in the upper left corner, updated once per four seconds.
3. Pressing it again: mini- window is closed, the desktop moves to the initial workspace of the window, the window is restored un- sticky and un- minimized.

#### Specifically for VirtualBox

When the VBox window is in front, it turns out Ubuntu shortcut keys are disabled(!), so the control script needs to be launched in another way. Below a few brief ones.

#### Option 1

I edited the control script. Now *only* in the case of VirtualBox:

- Click *anywhere* on the desktop, *Then* press your shortcut key. After that, simply use the shortcut key to show the window and exit.

  Explanation: The control script was made to exit if the window was of type "desktop", since you wouldn't want to minimize the desktop. Now the script first looks for possibly existing VirtualBox windows, to target, if the currently active window is the desktop.

#### Option 2

- Copy the icon below (right- click -> save as), save it as `minwinicon.png`

  [image]
- Copy the lines below into an empty file, save it as `minwin.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Name=Window Spy
  Exec=showcase_control 
  Icon=/path/to/minwinicon.png
  StartupNotify=false
  ```

  ***You'd need to log out and back in for the launcher to "find" the local `~/bin` path!***
  Drag the icon on to the launcher to use it.

The second solution has an important downside: after using it from the launcher, it will keep blinking for a few seconds, waiting for a window to appear. During that, clicking again won't have any effect. That *can* be solved, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/744191/72216), but including that in this answer would really make it too long. If you want to use option two, please look into the link.

Comment: So, good old `import` can do it, while the gnome-screenshot can't. Very, very interesting. I'm currious what exactly is the difference between the way they work

Comment: @Serg yeah, I was really surprised, thought it couldn't be done with just kitchen tools :)

Comment: Niccccceeeee :)

Comment: This is amazing. +1

Comment: @JacobVlijm - Glorious work! Maybe package it up as a deb for us plebs? :D

Comment: @ThatGuy working on it :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm This is phenomenal!  I'm most likely going to flag this as the answer.  However, as awesome (and elegant) as this solution is, it's missing something - I'd like to select a section of the workspace, not its entirety - is that something relatively easy to do now that you've got a working model?

Comment: @AnthonyK Wow, thanks :) a section would be difficult, since the image is window- oriented...

Comment: @AnthonyK just curious, but is there any reason not to accept the answer? It pretty much does exactly ehat you asked for (show preview of the window). You can test the ppa if you like.

Comment: @JacobVlijm - I've just installed the tool from your PPA and I *have to agree with you* - it does close to 100% what I was after - the only thing missing is a means of selecting a section/region of the workspace - the active window will do.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: @JacobVlijm - Is it possible to have the preview window be a movable window?  As it currently stands, if I have a maximized window in my current workspace, that preview window blocks whatever is underneath.

Comment: @AnthonyK It is! You can Alt-drag the window to any position :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm - Boy, that was embarrassingly simple - :(.  I've used ALT+Drag with mouse before when title bar was off screen.  Why didn't I think of that for this scenario???  No one can resolve a PEBKAC problem for me. Thanks.

Comment: @JacobVlijm While I appreciate what you've got here, is there no way to hook into the live Compiz previews that are used in the Switcher? Just tested and it's still possible to enable a 'live preview' on the Unity launcher, so they're still in the system somewhere...

Comment: @jymbob Thanks for the comment! They are no doubt in the system, but the question is if they are *available* from outside. If the developers do not provide a cli option or an API in any way, breaking into the code would be a job of a completely different order. I'd love to have the option though.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Fair point. Possibly more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595951/what-mechanism-does-compiz-use-when-copying-from-a-xclients-frontbuffer-to-the but way above my competence level!

Comment: @jymbob interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Something that seems like overkill but totally works for this purpose is [Open Broadcaster](https://obsproject.com/). In the "Sources" list box, click the plus, select "Window Capture", then follow the prompts to select the window you're interested in. No point in hitting record; just use the preview. It's available for [pretty much any OS](https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions), with instructions for Ubuntu [here](https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#ubuntu-installation), which I've copied below.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

If you feel like it, you can then go into the "View" menu and hide all the UI elements.