# is there any way to peek a desktop while in another? Some sort of "Desktop PIP"

Tags: unity

I use the virtual desktops. They are really handy.
Frequently, I leave something that takes some time to load/render/process running in a virtual desktop and then I switch to another to do other work. And to see whether the first task has finished or not, I usually hit SUPER+S just to have an eagle's view on the state of the processing [on the other desktops]. However, doing this I have to stop whatever I'm doing.

That's why I was wondering if is there any way that would give me such view [on just one other desktop, doesn't need to be able to see all the others] without having to [interrupt what I'm doing at the moment and] hit the SUPER+S? You know, a quick glance of eyes would do the trick; switching desktops (even using the handy shortcut CTRL+ALT+directional arrow makes my mind 'shift context' and thus loosing the focus)...

(I know that having two monitors would do the trick, but I don't have a fixed desk, hence have to rely only on the notebook I carry to everywhere... (sigh!))

Comment: You mean this? http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/window-preview-workspace-ubuntu If so see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/797614/can-i-have-a-window-showing-small-live-preview-of-another-workspace/846662#846662