# How can I monitor other windows non-intrusively (enable picture-in-picture feature) on GNOME 3?

Tags: software-recommendation, window, gnome-shell-extension, previews, gnome-shell

I am looking for an application or a GNOME Shell extension which I can use to easily and non-intrusively monitor other windows without having to have them on top in any way.

So I would like it to have the following features:

- The ability to show window previews of windows without having them on top and even showing minimized windows
- Allow showing the window preview in any corners of the screen
- Allow one with ease to view what is behind the window preview on screen and click on what is behind it
- Allow windows from different workspaces to be accessible
- Allow the resizing of the window preview
- Allow the switching on and off of the window preview with ease
- Allow the viewing of workspaces in the preview

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 with GNOME 3.24.1, is there such an extension?

This would be really useful for when I need to be monitoring a system application or I want to watch a film or a video call while doing work or other stuff and don't want to either have two windows taking up either half of the screen or to have to keep switching between them.

Comment: Related: [Can I have a window showing small live preview of another workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/q/797614/480481)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNOME Shell extension [Window Corner Preview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1227/window-corner-preview/) is exactly what you were looking for! Follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/757326/364819) in order to install it.

With Window Corner Preview simply select a window or workspace you wish to preview:

[image: Extension window/workspace selection]

And you will have the window in the top-right-hand corner (although if you left-click on the window preview you can make it go to the opposite corner, right-clicking the window preview will cause it to go to the next corner along in clockwise motion).

[image: Window preview]

If you wish to simply see what is behind the window preview just cursor over it and it will go mostly transparent:

[image: Window preview transparency]

To hide the window preview just use the `On/Off` slider you saw in the first screenshot which can be used once you have made a window or workspace selection from the list.

Comment: not working in ubuntu 20.04