# Way to get elementaryOS's picture-in-picture on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, interface, elementary

With version 5, elementaryOS introduced a picture-in-picture feature, allowing one to select any screen area and confine it to a floating rectangle above other windows. (Demoed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FbQzF6h8DA))

Is it possible to get this feature in Ubuntu?

**EDIT:** Just to further specify: I'm not looking for a full-screen window or a separate workspace in a picture-in-picture. What I'm looking for is elementaryOS's implementation of picture-in-picture, which allows picking any area within a window.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version and desktop environment? Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/797614/can-i-have-a-window-showing-small-live-preview-of-another-workspace

Comment: FYI: Official release announcement [is placed on Medium](https://medium.com/elementaryos/elementary-os-5-juno-is-here-471dfdedc7b3) with [screencast](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*bj4bWUEIDWjhDExwZMgsbA.gif).

Comment: I installed Elementary OS just to try the feature - yup, this is what I was hoping to get when I asked this question:
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/797614/can-i-have-a-window-showing-small-live-preview-of-another-workspace
It does exactly what I needed.  I hope someone can port that feature to Ubuntu 16.04/18.04.  In the meantime, I'm ok with what @jacobvlijm provided.