# How do I watch a Youtube in Picture-in-Picture (PIP) mode?

Tags: video, youtube, video-player

I'd like to watch youtube videos with a small video down in the corner without a lot of wasted space on the screen such as title bars, address bar, bookmarks bar, scroll bar, etc.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you mean by "a lot of wasted space"?

Comment: @danzel done. By space I mean visual space

Comment: Since this question is locked, I'll provide the answer as a comment.  If you are using Google Chrome, right-click 2 times with the pointer somewhere in the video and you'll see a *Picture-in-picture* option - click it and away you go.  Opera browser has a shortcut icon in the top middle of the video when you hover.

Comment: @AnthonyK very nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three options:

### VLC Method

- Open VLC
- Right click > enable Minimal Mode
- Right click titlebar in Unity > Always on Top (Unity has an option for all
  workspaces)
- "Play Network Stream" (Ctrl-N) and pasting the YouTube link of any video in the prompt

It's tedious because there's no youtube browsing, but its great for performance.

### Firefox Method

- One could [modify Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/977912/firefox-hide-everything-except-content-area-of-the-browser#978252)

### Workspace Method

- One could setup a live preview of a fullscreen youtube in another workspace: [Can I have a window showing small live preview of another workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797614/can-i-have-a-window-showing-small-live-preview-of-another-workspace)

### Google Chrome

Right-click twice with the pointer somewhere in the video and you'll see a Picture-in-picture option - click it and away you go.  - @AnthonyK

### Opera browser

Click the shortcut icon in the top middle of the video when you hover. – @AnthonyK

Comment: Please explain the steps to make this work in more detail. There is no "YouTube" in your answer.

Comment: @danzel Done. The network stream is just a more generic term for youtube.